# Definition of almost sure convergence from Casella & Berger

Tags: probability

In Casella and Berger, the definition of almost sure convergence of $\{X_n\}$ to $X$ is

$$P(\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty}|X_n - X| < \epsilon) = 1$$

for all $\epsilon > 0$.

I cannot figure why the inequality is necessary? Why not define it as:

$$P(\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty}|X_n - X| = 0) = 1$$

Assume some sequence is almost sure converges. Then, if there is some point in the sample space $s \in S$ such that the limit is not $0$, then there exists $\epsilon$ s.t. this limit is larger than this $\epsilon$. Thus, this $s$ must NOT belong to the subset of almost sure convergence. As such, we can remove all $s$ with limits which are not equal to zero. Thus, the second definition is created.

PS. Plz explain without measure theory. Set theory allowed ofc.

Comment: $\{\lim_n|X_n-X|=0\}=\bigcap_n\{\lim_n|X_n-X|<\varepsilon\}$. Theirs and yours notions are equivalent. I guess they defined this that way to make a parallel with the notion of convergence in measure for pedagogical purposes.

Comment: I suspect it makes the relationship with the Borel-Cantelli lemma easier to explain: thinking about $\sum_n \mathbb P(|X_n-X| \ge \epsilon)$ is useful while $\sum_n \mathbb P(|X_n-X| \not = 0)$ is not.